# Find duplicate labels in prometheus

Tags: prometheus, promql

we have multiple servers, with multiple customers on it. Sometimetimes we copy a customer  from  one server to another and then point the DNS to the new server.
Now, the problem is that the old server still reports some prometheus metrics for that customer, which results in duplicated datasets and bad data.

To clean the data, we need a way to identify those duplicated datasets.

Example Data:

```
orders(customer="a", server="1") = 200
orders(customer="b", server="1") = 299
orders(customer="c", server="2") = 10
orders(customer="a", server="2") = 10
```

What we are looking for is some PromQL to give us the following output:

```
a: 2
b: 1
c: 1
```

Note that I am not interested in the values here - just in the number of unique datapoints.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `count` and group by (using the `by` keyword) the label you want to sum, in you case `customer`

```
count(orders) by (customer)
```

Take a look at this [live example](http://demo.robustperception.io:9090/graph?g0.expr=count(alertmanager_alerts_received_total)%20by%20(status)&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=1h)

Comment: Hello @felipe, unfortunately this is not outputing what I was looking for, since this is `sum`ing the values of the `orders`. However, I am not interested in the values at all. I am interested in the number of datasets with the same label. I'll edit my question to make this more clear.

Comment: @flix try to use `count`. I edited my answer.